# Using a variable as part of a `this.state` call ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to created a form validation using `react-bootstrap`, and would like to avoid making a validation function for each input.

I have this input:

```
<Input 
  hasFeedback 
  type="text" 
  label="Username" 
  bsStyle={this.state.UsernameStyle} 
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'Username')} 
  value={this.state.Username} 
  bsSize="large" 
  ref="inptUser" 
  placeholder="Enter Username"
/>
```

Plus, I have two function to handle the validation and updating of the state:

```
handleChange: function(name, e) {
  var state = {};
  state[name] = e.target.value;
  this.setState(state);
  var namestyle  = name + 'Style';
  this.setState(this.validationState(namestyle, e));
},
```

&

```
validationState: function(style, event) {
  var length = event.target.value.length;

  if (length > 4) this.setState({style: 'success'});
  else if (length > 2) this.setState({style: 'warning'});

  return {style};
}
```

At this point if I change `style` to `Username` I can get this solution to work for that specific input as well. I could make an if statement and depending on the string I get in `style` I can call the appropriate setState, but is their a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoosh I don't think you should be calling `setState` in your `validationState` function... it should do some validation and pass the result back to original `setState` caller in `handleChange`. You have `setState` inception right now.

Comment: Haha you cracked me up with `setState` inception! I was thinking about how this could cause any issues, but it seems to be working fine so far. I'm going to see if I can find a better solution for this though.

Answer (score 17):

```
var yourVariable = "name";
this.state[yourVariable];
```

is equivelant to:

```
this.state.name;
```

if you want to use your variable in set state you can use this:

```
var value = "peter";
this.setState({[yourVariable]: value});
```

is equivelant to:

```
this.setState({name: value)};
```

Comment: But why not just use yourVariable as value for a component without double it in this.state[yourVariable], and to refresh component use this.setState({})?

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` should collect all of the information required to change state and call `setState` a single time.  `vaslidationState` should *not* be changing state.  It should just be returning the new style:

```
validationState(value) {
    return (value.length > 4) ? "success" : (value.length > 2) ? "warning" : "error";
}

handleChange(name, e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const style = this.validationState(value);
    const stateUpdates = {
        [name]: value,
        [`${name}Style`]: style
    };
    this.setState(stateUpdates);
}
```

Comment: I apologize in advance for my inexperience!

I understand what you are doing in the validationState, but I'm having trouble understanding how the `const stateUpdates = {
        [name]: value,
        ["${name}Style"]: style
    };` changes the state of my already existing variables so it reflects on the input.

Again sorry for my ignorance and thank you for your help!